# DataTable not sorting C#

Tags: c#, sorting, datatable

For this project, I have to sort a DataTable by a certain column, the 'Checked' column. What this does is allow me to see the order in which each row was checked for any abnormalities. At the moment, this column looks like this:-

```
Checked
-------
0
2
3
4
6
7
10
1
11
12 
5
8
9
```

The problem I have is that the table is not sorting by this column. Because of this, it checks rows that do not need to be checked. The code I currently use is:-

```
public void setTableData(DataTable table)
{
    table.DefaultView.Sort = "Checked ASC";
    table = table.DefaultView.ToTable();
    tblProduct.DataSource = table;
}
```

After looking at different websites and from other programmers advice, I still cant see a problem with this code. What is causing the table to be unsortable?

Comment: What type of object is `tblProduct`?  It could be that your sort is working correctly but it's not refreshing after you set the `DataSource`.

Comment: tblProduct is a DataGridView object. I added a refresh command in there and it still does not work.

Comment: Refresh does not do what you intend it to do here.  Try setting the DataSource to null before setting it to the table.  Otherwise you will need to get into BindingSource changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what is your `Checked` Value? is it `bool` ?

for Sorting Data in DataTable you can try this :

```
 DataView dv = table.DefaultView;

   dv.Sort = "Checked desc";
   DataTable sortedDT = dv.ToTable();
```

Your code for sorting is true , but we can't compile your code .I think its appear for data in `Checked` Value was wrong  .
Can you post `Checked` Data or ?

Comment: Based on the sample data in the question, it does not appear to be `bool`.

Comment: It's an `integer` column